# How to get the friendly url with facebook graph search api results?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

if I got a

```
 [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 364728713652547_384117421713676
                [from] => Array
                    (
                        [category] => Professional services
```

the id is facebook authorid_postid
so the link is https://www.facebook.com/364728713652547_384117421713676

I want to get the 76 in the like butoon '76 like this' on page.

when I use FQL with

```
SELECT comment_count, like_count, share_count, click_count, total_count from link_stat where url='https://www.facebook.com/364728713652547_384117421713676'
```

I got a result of

```
{"data": [
{
  "comment_count": 0, 
  "like_count": 0, 
  "share_count": 0, 
  "click_count": 0, 
  "total_count": 0
}]}
```

and if I click at title 
I  redirect to a page which url is : https://www.facebook.com/pages/Knowles-Gripping-Services/364728713652547?ref=stream

then I use FQL again

```
SELECT comment_count, like_count, share_count, click_count, total_count from link_stat where url='https://www.facebook.com/pages/Knowles-Gripping-Services/364728713652547?ref=stream'
```

I got the right result I want:

```
{"data": [{
  "comment_count": 0, 
  "like_count": 76, 
  "share_count": 0, 
  "click_count": 0, 
  "total_count": 76
}]}
```

so,Is anyone knows is there a way to get the 'redirected page url' in facebook api ? (I don't want to use php and read http header)
or get the like_count with post_id?
thank you very much.